# If $ f > 0 $, $g\ge0$, and $ \int_a^b g > 0 $, then $ \int_a^b fg > 0 $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $ f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be continuous on $ [a,b] $ and $ f > 0 $ on $ (a,b) $, and let $ g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be non-negative and integrable on $ [a,b] $. 
If $ f > 0 $, and $$ \int_a^b g > 0 \,, $$ then is it true that $$ \int_a^b fg > 0 \,? $$ 
The integrals are Riemann integrals.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be true. However, to answer, it would help to have some context. What is the exact statement of the question? Where does this question comes from? What did you try?

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe your $g(x)=x$ is not non-negative on $[-1,1]$

Comment: I have given an answer in context of Riemann integrals. You may clarify if your question deals with the Riemann integral or the Lebesgue one.

Comment: The Lebesgue case is simple since $A\mapsto \int_A g$ is a (unsigned) measure and integral of $f$ with respect to it is precisely $\int fg$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extension to the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals is

> **Proposition.** If $ f,g $ are continuous on $ [a,b] $ and $ g(x) > 0 $, for all $ x \in [a,b] $, then there exists $ c \in (a,b) $ such that $$ \int_a^b fg = f(c) \int_a^b g \,. $$

which is taken from Exercise 17 of Section 7.2 from Bartle and Sherbert's Introduction to Real Analysis.

Applying this gives the desired result, since $ f > 0 $.

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses Riemann integrals.

If $g$ is non-negative and has a positive integral then it is positive in some subinterval which implies that $fg$ is non-negative and positive in some sub-interval. Thus it has a positive integral. Continuity of $f$ is not needed. Rather the following non-trivial theorem is needed :

> **Theorem**: If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ with a positive integral then $f $ is positive on some sub-interval of $[a, b] $.

Comment: You mean it is positive in non null set? positive somewhere is not enough

Comment: @Holo: I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Bungo: one more update done. I am not even a beginner in Lebesgue integrals so can't comment on that.

Comment: Isn't the theorem an immediate consequence of the fact that a nonnegative Riemann integrable function whose integral is $I > 0$ can be approximated function can be approximated from below by a nonnegative step function whose integral is at least $I/2$? Which in turn follows directly from the characterization of Riemann integrals in terms of upper and lower sums. Apologies if I'm missing a subtlety.

Comment: @Bungo: I read a different proof in Apostol's Mathematical Analysis but your argument also looks fine (and perhaps simpler). Apostol uses Riemann sums directly, but his argument is similar in spirit.

Answer (score 0):

If $\epsilon>0$ is small enough, then $\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon}g>0$.  Moreover, $f\ge C(\epsilon)>0$ on $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]$, so 
$$
\int_a^b fg\ge \int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon}fg\ge C(\epsilon)\int_{a+\epsilon}^{b-\epsilon}g,
$$
which is positive.